Django middleware can record request log, but django async view somethings was not executed
request will be recorded by the middleware and executed in async view, but in some cases, it will not be executed in view.
Settings:
Python: 3.10.12
Django: 4.2.1
middleware settings:
MIDDLEWARE = [
    "django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware",
    "django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware",
    "corsheaders.middleware.CorsMiddleware",
    "django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware",
    "django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware",
    "django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware",
    "django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware",
    ...
    "utils.middleware.RequestMiddleware",
]

RequestMiddleware:
class RequestMiddleware(MiddlewareMixin):
    def process_view(self, request, view_func, view_args, view_kwargs):
        req_str = "reqeust user:{} request method:{} request path:{} request body:{}".format(
            request.user,
            request.META["REQUEST_METHOD"],
            request.path,
            request.body
        )
        logger.info(req_str)
        return None

    def process_response(self, request, response):
        data = response.content
        data = data.decode("utf-8")
        logger.info("response status code:{} data:{}".format(response.status_code, data))
        return response

    def process_exception(self, request, exception):
        logger.error(traceback.format_exc())

views.py:
async def report(request):
    my_views.delay()  # celery task
    return send_message({"result": 0})

